# Is there a better way to define a conditional type?

Tags: typescript

I have a HATEOAS API that gives me structures based on my request. At the heart of it, it could be a single entity or an array of entities.

```
// single entity
{
    links: [{ ... }],
    data: {
        links: [{ ... }],
        data: {
           id: 1,
           title: "example entity"
        }
    }
}

// array of entities
{
    links: [{ ... }],
    data: [{
        links: [{ ... }],
        data: {
           id: 1,
           title: "example entity"
        }
    }, {
        links: [{ ... }],
        data: {
           id: 2,
           title: "another entity"
    }]
}
```

My generic types for all responses are as follows

```
type Link = {
    href: string;
    ref: string;
    type: string;
}

type EntityResponse<T> = { links: Link[], data: T };

type Response<T, Type extends [] | undefined> = {
    links: Link[];
    data: Type extends []
        ? EntityResponse<T>[]
        : EntityResponse<T>;
}
```

Ideally I would be able to type the data using the entities type

```
Response<Product>

// or

Response<Product[]>
```

But as each of the entities is interpolated with a `links` object it made it much trickier so I came up with the above.

So that if I wanted to define an array type response I would type it as follows
`Response<Product, []>`

For a single entity, I would type it
`Response<Product>`

I have a suspicion that I could remove the second type used conditionally but I'm unsure how I would achieve it given that I need to add the `links` key/value pair into each individual entity and I don't want to add this to the entity type. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Product` or `Product[]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that would have been ideal if it wasn't for the additional `links` component of the data object

Comment: Added a little more clarity to the question. I would love to use `Product` or `Product[]` but I couldn't find a way to do it with the interpolated `links` key/value pair.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the infer keyword for this special purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a conditional type that [infers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) the potential array elements, you will be to able use `Response<Product>` and `Response<Product[]>` to define your response types:

```
type Response<T> = {
    links: Link[];
    data: T extends (infer E)[]
        ? EntityResponse<E>[]
        : EntityResponse<T>;
}
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&module=199#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgOwNZQLxQN4Cgq6gCwCcIAzALigGdhDEBzAbhz2PKpvqbylEgutoJGWAL5YsvaAFEEwOKABKESmAD2CShAA8AFQB8aTFAA2iJJQrxkAbQC6AGigATAIbAXFHVBFMJ4aEoq6pq6BujY3KbIFrBmdlx4ru6eUBAAHsAQCE6UUAAUiCQQhFBSAJR2zNy4APylsvIggWoa2lJ6ldV4FDJyisotIfpMYn6QUAAKhKpOAK4AxsCGEXgILgC2EPwcQiPi88FLYNNzixTNwdpTMwvAYZhVJmYxdvaPSR4PXbhR5hSvj24HwoGCga02FAA5NdTksAIKQ7yPMQ+faHKDHG6LGIXVpaGG3Oz3FY-Z7-BzvNyfawk6q-F4U77OKkgsEbLZQaEnW5QBFI7giRy0yJkqAApnAozgjlcrFLABCiLEAtsogYQA)

Comment: I really should learn about `infer`, thanks for your help Robby, it works exactly as expected.